# i can't connect to tor newtork

Tags: network-configuration

05/09/2017 14:45:57 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
05/09/2017 14:45:57 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
05/09/2017 14:45:57 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
05/09/2017 14:45:57 PM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
05/09/2017 14:45:57 PM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay descriptors 
05/09/2017 14:46:18 PM.700 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host 230A8B2A8BA861210D9B4BA97745AEC217A94207 at 163.172.176.167:443) 
05/09/2017 14:46:18 PM.700 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
05/09/2017 14:46:18 PM.700 [WARN]  9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 11; recommendation warn; host 92ECC9E0E2AF81BB954719B189AC362E254AD4A5 at 91.219.237.244:443) 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.600 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.600 [WARN]  10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 12; recommendation warn; host B0553175AADB0501E5A61FC61CEA3970BE130FF2 at 5.9.147.226:9001) 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.600 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.600 [WARN]  11 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 13; recommendation warn; host 6EF897645B79B6CB35E853B32506375014DE3621 at 80.127.137.19:443) 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.600 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.600 [WARN]  12 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
05/09/2017 14:46:24 PM.800 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here

/6/2017 22:36:20 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2017 22:36:20 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2017 22:36:20 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2017 22:36:20 PM.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/6/2017 22:36:20 PM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
9/6/2017 22:38:09 PM.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/6/2017 22:38:09 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2017 22:38:09 PM.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/6/2017 22:38:09 PM.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
9/6/2017 22:38:14 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2017 22:38:14 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2017 22:38:14 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2017 22:38:14 PM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/6/2017 22:38:49 PM.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 80%: Connecting to the Tor network. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host FBD20387F64D67ED53AC5BD2E0302D44B2DA360C at 192.99.57.111:9001) 
9/6/2017 22:38:49 PM.900 [WARN] 14 connections have failed: 
9/6/2017 22:38:49 PM.900 [WARN]  14 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
9/6/2017 22:38:59 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/6/2017 22:38:59 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/6/2017 22:38:59 PM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/6/2017 22:38:59 PM.800 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.